# Debugging name resolution with Windows and APIPA

Tags: windows, ip, hostname, mdns, zeroconf

For lab equipment I use default settings everywhere and they use **IP auto configuration** (APIPA aka zeroconf I think); I've put them on a private switch.

I was always able to to address them via their host name, I think this works via mDNS.

Now I replaced one device with an identical one and suddenly this stopped working:

```
C:\>ping FSW26-101414
Ping request could not find host FSW26-101414. Please check the name and try aga
in.
```

The instruments is surely up and the hostname definitely correct:

```
C:\>ping 169.254.27.85

Pinging 169.254.27.85 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 169.254.27.85: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 169.254.27.85: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 169.254.27.85: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 169.254.27.85: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 169.254.27.85:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

What could be the reason for that?
Is the issue the "host" or the "client"?
How can I debug this?

Comment: How are you expecting the name to resolve to an IP address?  WINS?  DNS?

Comment: That's part of my question ... but I assume it's mDNS. I wrote it's AIPA (i.e., zeroconf), so no DHCP, DNS etc.

Comment: Try resolving the hostname manually using nslookup.

Comment: I think nslookip is just for DNS. If I use it, it queries my main DNS server. Of course the hostname won't be found that way.

Comment: Are you running Windows 10 1511 or later?  Prior versions of windows don't natively support mDNS.

Comment: Windows uses NetBios or DNS out of the box typically. Any device that isn’t windows based isn’t going to show up by hostname in a windows network.  In addition NetBios can not be blocked on your firewall or disabled on the network interface. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/172218/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order

Comment: If you were able to ping host names without adding .local to the end, then you were probably resolving them via NetBIOS Name Service broadcasts, not mDNS.

Comment: @Spiff: Depends on the client used. While Bonjour requires .local to be explicitly specified, the integrated mDNS client in recent Win10 builds doesn't. (Whether you add .local or not, it automagically uses both mDNS and LLMNR.)

Comment: Ah ok then it's NetBIOS. For the devices which are working, adding ".local" does not work. Host OS is Win7 and the clients are a combination of Linux (!) and Win7 Embedded. The questions is then how to debug this with NetBIOS. Again, same device (Rohde & Schwarz FSW) used to work; I just changed the device to a different one.

Comment: The solution is: NetBIOS must be enabled on the interface and the interface must be set as Home/Work network (NOT public), otherwise the firewall blocks netbios.

Answer (score 1):

Local name resolution may use several protocols. Grouped by client OS:

- Windows 10 (not sure which releases, but *approximately* 10.1803 or later) support the Apple [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) protocol (UDP multicast to port 5353). Name queries are sent to multicast groups 224.0.0.251 and FF02::FB. This doesn't depend on IP configuration (despite being part of the Zeroconf suite it doesn't use nor imply APIPA nor vice versa). It *appears* to be active whenever LLMNR is active.

  (If you have iTunes installed, regardless of Windows version, it installs its own mDNS client – Apple Bonjour – as a Winsock LSP. Bonjour only resolves names with the `.local` suffix, while the built-in client accepts single-label no-TLD names as well.)
- Windows Vista and Server 2008 and later support the [LLMNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-Local_Multicast_Name_Resolution) protocol (UDP multicast to port 5355). Name queries are sent to multicast groups 224.0.0.252 and FF02::1:3. This doesn't depend on IP configuration; it is active as long as Network Discovery is active.
- All Windows versions support the [NetBIOS Name Service](https://wiki.wireshark.org/NetBIOS/NBNS) protocol (UDP/IPv4 broadcast to port 137, as well as some *complex* "master browser" election). As far as I understand it, name queries are broadcast. This doesn't depend on IP configuration, but it does require SMBv1 to be installed and enabled.

I don't know what "lab equipment" you use, but any of those protocols *might* be supported by non-Windows devices. (For example, on Linux, mDNS is implemented by Avahi or mDNSResponder; LLMNR is implemented by systemd-resolved or xllmnrd; NBNS is implemented by Samba nmbd.) Many devices speak mDNS. Printers tend to speak all three and more.

How to troubleshoot the multicast-based protocols:

1. Install a [packet capture tool](https://www.wireshark.org/).
2. Point it at your LAN interface.
3. Try to resolve a name, see if your computer generates the expected LLMNR or mDNS query packets and if the other device generates any replies.
4. Reboot the other device (or just reconnect it to the network), and see if that device announces its own name *registration* packets.

Note that `nslookup` is *not* a general name lookup tool. It is *strictly* a unicast DNS client and doesn't help with mDNS/LLMNR/NBNS at all.

Comment: Based on your comments it must be NetBIOS (Host: Win7 Embedded, Client: Win7). Do you also have an idea how to debug the NetBIOS name resolution?

Comment: Based on my comments it must be either NetBIOS or LLMNR, because Win7 is later than WinVista...  Use the same tools either way – start a packet capture, try to resolve a name, and see what packets show up.